# Java stream min/max of separate variables

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, max, min

How can I determine both the **min** and **max** of *different* attributes of objects in a stream?

I've seen answers on how get min and max of the *same variable*. I've also seen answers on how to get min or max using a particular object attribute (e.g. `maxByAttribute()`). But how do I get both the min of all the "x" attributes and the max of all the "y" attributes of objects in a stream?

Let's say I have a Java `Stream<Span>` with each object having a `Span.getStart()` and `Span.getEnd()` returning type `long`. (The units are irrelevant; it could be time or planks on a floor.) I want to get the **minimum start** and the **maximum end**, e.g. to represent the minimum span covering all the spans. Of course, I could create a loop and manually update mins and maxes, but is there a concise and efficient functional approach using Java streams?

*Note that I don't want to create intermediate spans!* If you want to create some intermediate `Pair<Long>` instance that would work, but for my purposes the `Span` type is special and I can't create more of them. I just want to find the minimum start and maximum end.

Bonus for also showing whether this is possible using the new Java 12 `teeing()`, but for my purposes the solution must work in Java 8+.

Comment: What is the data type of `start` and `end`?

Comment: Let's say they are `long` values. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all data is valid (`end > start`) you can create [`LongSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LongSummaryStatistics.html) object containing such information as *min/max* values, *average*, etc., by  using `summaryStatistics()` as a terminal operation.

```
List<Span> spans = // initiliazing the source
    
LongSummaryStatistics stat = spans.stream()
    .flatMapToLong(span -> LongStream.of(span.getStart(), span.getEnd()))
    .summaryStatistics();
        
long minStart = stat.getMin();
long maxEnd = stat.getMax();
```

***Note*** that if the stream source would be empty (y*ou can check it by invoking* `stat.getCount()`, *which will give the number of consumed elements*), *min* and *max* attributes of the `LongSummaryStatistics` object would have their default values, which are maximum and minimum long values respectively.

---

That is how it could be done using `collect()` and picking *max* and *min* values manually:

```
long[] minMax = spans.stream()
    .collect(() -> new long[2],
        (long[] arr, Span span) -> { // consuming the next value
            arr[0] = Math.min(arr[0], span.getStart());
            arr[1] = Math.max(arr[1], span.getEnd());
        },
        (long[] left, long[] right) -> { // merging partial results produced in different threads
            left[0] = Math.min(left[0], right[0]);
            left[1] = Math.max(left[1], right[1]);
        });
```

---

In order to utilize `Collectors.teeing()` you need to define two *collectors* and a *function*. Every element from the stream will be consumed by both collectors at the same time and when they are done, `merger` function will grab their intermediate results and will produce the final result.

In the example below, the result is `Optional` of map entry. In case there would be no elements in the stream, the resulting optional object would be empty as well.

```
List<Span> spans = List.of(new Span(1, 3), new Span(3, 6), new Span(7, 9));
        
Optional<Map.Entry<Long, Long>> minMaxSpan = spans.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.teeing(
        Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingLong(Span::getStart)),
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingLong(Span::getStart)),
        (Optional<Span> min, Optional<Span> max) ->
            min.isPresent() ? Optional.of(Map.entry(min.get().getStart(), max.get().getEnd())) : Optional.empty()));
        
minMaxSpan.ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
1=9
```

As an alternative data-carrier, you can use a Java 16 record:

```
public record MinMax(long start, long end) {}
```

Getters in the form `start()` and `end()` will be generated by the compiler.

Comment: Your example shows me how to get the min start. It doesn't show getting the max end. And either `maxEnd = stat.getMin()` is a typo, or you missed one of the requirements.

Comment: @GarretWilson Sorry, it's a typo.

Comment: Still your code doesn't even call `span.getEnd()`, so I don't know how I could be getting the max of it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typos. Oh, I see; you're just putting all the mins and maxes into a single stream, and then finding the min and max values (via `summaryStatistics()`) from the flattened values. You no longer care which is `Span.getStart()` or `Span.getEnd()`, or if they overlap. You just want the min and max value. Interesting approach.

Comment: @GarretWilson Sure, I expect that `start` and `end` will overlap, but as I've said if start will be always less than end it will have no impact on finding the *max end* and *min start*.

Comment: Yes, I understand; that was not a criticism. When I said "you don't care" I meant "the algorithm does not pay attention to whether one or more span overlaps, because it doesn't seem to affect the outcome". I was just pointing out one interesting aspect of your approach.

Comment: @GarretWilson It's OK, I think the simpler approach - the better. Here we're not dealing directly with the task of picking the lowest and the greatest values (although it's not complicated) but relying on existing functionality. The same result can be achieved by utilizing `collect` and controlling this process manually.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid for pre Java 12 you need to operate on the given Stream twice.

Given a class Span

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
static class Span {
    int start;
    int end;
}
```

and a list of spans

```
List<Span> spanList = List.of(new Span(1,2),new Span(3,4),new Span(5,1));
```

you could do something like below for java 8:

```
Optional<Integer> minimumStart = spanList.stream().map(Span::getStart).min(Integer::compareTo);
Optional<Integer> maximumEnd = spanList.stream().map(Span::getEnd).max(Integer::compareTo);
```

For Java 12+ as you already noticed you can use the built-in teeing collector like:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> result = spanList.stream().collect(
        Collectors.teeing(
                Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Span::getStart)),
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Span::getEnd)),
                (min, max) -> {
                    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap();
                    map.put("minimum start", min.get().getStart());
                    map.put("maximum end", max.get().getEnd());
                    return map;
                }
        ));

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Collectors.teeing` solution using a record as the Span class.

```
record Span(long getStart, long getEnd) {
}

List<Span> spans = List.of(new Span(10,20), new Span(30,40));
```

- the Collectors in teeing are built upon each other. In this case
- `mapping` - to get the longs out of the Span class
- `maxBy, minBy` - takes a comparator to get the max or min value as appropriate
  Both of these return `optionals` so `get` must be used.
- `merge` operation - to merge the results of the teed collectors.
- final results are placed in a `long` array

```
long[] result =
        spans.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.teeing(
                        Collectors.mapping(Span::getStart,
                                Collectors.minBy(
                                        Long::compareTo)),
                        Collectors.mapping(Span::getEnd,
                                Collectors.maxBy(
                                        Long::compareTo)),
                        (a, b) -> new long[] { a.get(),
                                b.get() }));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

prints

```
[10, 40]
```

You can also use `collectingAndThen` to put them in an array after get the values from Summary statistics.

```
long[] results = spans.stream().flatMap(
        span -> Stream.of(span.getStart(), span.getEnd()))
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.summarizingLong(Long::longValue),
                stats -> new long[] {stats.getMin(),
                        stats.getMax()}));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```

prints

```
[10, 40]
```